# I cannot run vim in 16.04

Tags: vim, ruby

I tried running vim today, and I got an error:

```
vim: error while loading shared libraries: libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then after a lot of research, I searched the [libruby packages available for 16.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libruby) and there is no libruby1.9 available for 16.04.

I don't know how to proceed. Vim seems to require this package, but it no longer exists.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep vim
ii  vim                                           2:8.0.0329-0york1~16.04                       amd64        Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor
ii  vim-common                                    2:8.0.0329-0york1~16.04                       all          Vi IMproved - Common files
rc  vim-gnome                                     2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3                            amd64        Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with GNOME2 GUI
rc  vim-gui-common                                2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3                            all          Vi IMproved - Common GUI files
ii  vim-runtime                                   2:8.0.0329-0york1~16.04                       all          Vi IMproved - Runtime files
ii  vim-tiny                                      2:8.0.0329-0york1~16.04                       amd64        Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - compact version
```

Comment: Did you try installing the `libruby` that is listed there?

Comment: Please share : dpkg -l | grep vim   Here on my 16.04 vim-nox only needs /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.3.so.2.3

Comment: @Terrance I did. I have it installed. And I tried reinstalling it.

Comment: @Albertj 
Interesting. I tried reinstalling VIM as well, but it keeps giving me the same error message.

Comment: I agree with albertj.  Please show the output of `dpkg -l | grep vim` as you probably have a package installed that uses that ruby library that might need to be reinstalled itself or removed.

Comment: @terrance Ok, I included the output of said command.

Comment: @albertj I included the output of the command you suggested

Comment: The only one I see on your list that uses libruby is `vim-gnome`.  Maybe you might want to try reinstalling that one.  `sudo apt install --reinstall vim-gnome`

Comment: @Terrance Ok, something weird is going on. I uninstalled all of the above and I tried to run vim, and I still get the same error.

Comment: @Terrance Is there a command where I can see what the OS is trying to run when I type 'vim' ?

Comment: @Terrance Ok, so I input 'which vim' and it returned /usr/bin/vim and sure enough the file is there even though I supposedly uninstalled vim. Can I just manually delete this file and reinstall or will that cause problems?

Comment: I guess you could always purge the install, then reinstall.  `sudo apt remove --purge vim-*` then `sudo apt install vim`

Comment: @Terrance The purge didn't work. I did a manual sudo rm /usr/bin/vim. Then I reinstalled vim from the repo and now it works. Weird.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it worked.  Maybe your vim was installed via another package.  Happy Ubuntuing!  =)

Answer (score 1):

With the comments already, something that you can try is to reinstall all `vim` packages that are installed already on your system.

Run the following command in a terminal window to reinstall all packages that `vim` has:

```
dpkg -l | grep vim | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo apt install --reinstall
```

Hope that helps!